# Regex: How can I find a words beginning with Ä,Ö,Ü ...?

Tags: javascript, regex

I search for words in a text with:

```
var newWords = data.match(/\b[^\s\d,-.:!?{}\"“\[\]']+/g);
```

This works, except for words that begin with letters like Ä, Ö, Ü, which is perfectly possible in the German language.

What I would really like to do, is to write the search above like

```
var newWords = data.match(/\b[^\W\d]+/g);
```

But this leaves me completly without ä, ö, ü in the words. ß is also missing.

Is there a nice solution for it?

Comment: Using an alternative regex engine like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) would allow you to use Unicode character classes `\p{L}` (which would match any letter in any language, including Umlauts). With vanilla JS regex you are forced to mention any letter you'd like to match explicitly (`[öäüß\w]`) - and word boundaries will never work at Umlauts.

Comment: Thanks. I installed it for node.js. But I couldn't figure out the syntax for it ... didn't find the regular match method ... I tried:   var w = XRegExp('\b\\p{L}+'), newWords = XRegExp.exec(data,w); with empty array as result. What is wrong?

Comment: You are right, XRegExp does not re-implement `\b`, so word boundaries are not going to work. You can still use XRegExp (given that you include the Unicode addon), as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/twa44ygj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple solution I suggest to use

```
var newWords = data.match(/[\w\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\xff]+/g);
```

This matches strings consisting only of letters A-Z in any case as well as all letters with code value 192 to 255 in code page [ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which is similar to [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) with the exception of the [multiplication sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign) and the [obelus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelus) as long as the `data` string contains just North American and Western European text.

With the expression

```
var newWords = data.match(/[\w\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff]+/g);
```

the Unicode values of the special language specific letters in ISO/IEC 8859-1 respectively Windows-1252 are explicitly specified and therefore other letters of other languages like Eastern European languages are ignored by the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple match them, using the ascii codes you want to match:

```
^\xD6nder$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lSAOI4fw_Ly-BY9k)

`\xD6` would be `Ö` (`D6` is hex of ascii code `214`). You can lookup more hex values here: http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm